# jQuery Autocomplete not getting updated value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the value in text box and its working  but the main problem is when I update the vendor from select box the `current_vendor` variable changes its value but in autocomplete function source URL keeps the old value of `current_vendor` which is `0` instead of new one I don't know what I am doing wrong or missing here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var current_vendor = 0;                    
$("select[name=txtvendor]").change(function() {
    var current_vendor = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
});
$("input#ProdDescription").autocomplete({
    source: "includes/modProducts/search-products.php?viewVendor="+current_vendor,
    minLength: 1,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        var item = ui.item;
            if(item) {
                $(this).closest('.row').find('.txtchassis').val(item.ChassisNo);
                $(this).closest('.row').find('.txtdescription').val(item.BikeDescription);
                $(this).closest('.row').find('.txtprice').val(item.SellingAmount);

                $(this).closest('.row').find('.txtbikeid').val(item.BikeID);
                $(this).closest('.row').find('.txtcostprice').val(item.CostPrice);
                $(this).closest('.row').find('.txtcolorcode').val(item.ColorCode);
            }
        }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `AutoComFunction()` function to update values of `current_vendor` variable try this code it will resolve the problem

```
$("select[name=txtvendor]").change(function() {
vendor_code = this.value;
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
AutoComFunction();
}).change();
```